# Reset slider to default on MATLAB GUIDE

Tags: matlab, slider, reset, matlab-guide

I'm doing an equalizer, with three slides for low, medium and high frequencies.
To set the default value to 0dB(1), the sliders have to start on the middle. I got it working like this:

```
function interfaz_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
set(handles.low,'Value',0.5);
handles.low=initialvalue;
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

I want to make a button so that when you press it, it makes the slider go back to the initial value. I've tried this way:

```
function eq_reset_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
set(handles.low,'Value',0.5);
handles.low=initialvalue;
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

This causes the next error:

```
Error using handle.handle/set
Invalid or deleted object.

Error in interfaz>eq_reset_Callback (line 644)
set(handles.low,'Value',0.5);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in interfaz (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
@(hObject,eventdata)interfaz('eq_reset_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Any ideas why this happens? Alternative ways to do it?

Comment: You are overwriting the handle with `handles.low=initialvalue;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

The opening function :

```
function interfaz_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
handles.low_initialvalue = 0.5;
set(handles.low,'Value',handles.low_initialvalue);
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

The button callback function :

```
function eq_reset_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
set(handles.low,'Value',handles.low_initialvalue);
guidata(hObject, handles);
```